# "/dev/ttyUSB0" equivalent in windows

Tags: c, ubuntu, usb, tty, com-port

In Linux I can write and read data from an USB device by calling C's `fopen('/dev/ttyUSB0', 'rw')`

Specifically what is the equivalent of the directory "/dev/ttyUSB0" in windows
I'd like to do the same in windows for COM3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a runtime environment like Cygwin or msys-2.0.dll which provides a POSIX compatibility, you can run `ls /dev/tty*` in the shell provided by the environment to see what kind of entries you get.  It looks like COM3 would correspond to `/dev/ttyS2`, at least with msys-2.0.dll.

If you are writing a native Windows program, you should be able to open "COM3" with `fopen` or `CreateFile`.  Using `CreateFile` is probably better than `fopen` because it returns a native Windows handle which allows you to use the `SetCommTimeouts` and `SetCommState` API functions.  COM ports higher than COM9 need a prefix of `\\.\`, which is written as `"\\\\.\\"` in C because we need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Please also note that using `"\\\\.\\"` is always possible for devices (also for COM1-COM9): `CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM1", ...)`